# Common lisp and infix package

Tags: common-lisp, eval, infix-notation

There is the infix package for common lisp (see http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/lang/lisp/code/syntax/infix/infix.cl), which transforms infix form to prefix.

For example:

```
(string->prefix "1+2") ;; => (+ 1 2)
```

It also provides the reader macro #I, which can evaluate an infix form, e.g.,

```
#I(1+2) ;; => 3
```

But I don't want to use this reader macro.

I have written a simple function, which uses cl-ppcre, to substitute a string with a number, i.e.,

```
(prepare-form "1+x*x" "x" 3) ;; => "1+3*3"
```

Finally, I have a function which evaluates the infix form

```
(defun eval-infix (form &rest args)
  (eval (string->prefix (apply #'prepare-form form args))))
```

Can the function eval-infix be implemented without using the eval function?
My final goal is to call eval-infix like this:

```
(eval-infix "1+x*x" "x" (+ 1 2))
```

Comment: 1) Why do you want to avoid eval but are ok with calling eval-infix? 2) Do you want eval-infix to work for all CL forms or a subset of the language?

Comment: 1) Because I don't want eval-infix to have the same security issues that eval has. 2) Optimally, eval-infix should work on a (math) subset of the language. 3) Basically, I am confused because I don't see in the infix package a call to the eval function. I suspect it is hidden in "set-dispatch-macro-character". If not, then it is implemented without a call to eval, which is what I want to succeed.

Comment: The infix package doesn't need to call `EVAL`, because the reader macro transforms the infix syntax to prefix at read time, so it will be compiled as if the infix never existed. You'd have to use a macro or a reader macro rather than a function to do the same. Notice however that substituting values into the string won't work at macroexpansion time, because the values are only known at run time. Using string replacements to generate code is a pretty questionable thing to do anyway. You should instead just let the generated code refer to the variables as usual.

Comment: If the strings aren't known at compile time, and the strings aren't fully trusted, you could also write an interpreter for a safe mathematical language instead of even trying to mangle it into CL.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations! I started eval-infix as a macro, but I wanted to have also the possibility of (eval-infix "1+x*x" "x" (+ 1 2)), so I changed it to a function using eval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think what you want to use is `string->prefix`. This will intern symbols so to avoid polluting your own package lets define one. Finally you can avoid the security problems of eval by defining your own eval. There is still a problem where symbols from other packages can be written and this makes me sad. There is also the problem that the infix reader can escape to the Lisp reader which can do arbitrary evaluation. Here is a sketch of the parts of the solution. I’ve probably got the arguments for some functions in the wrong order.

```
(defpackage infix-vars)
(defun read-infix-string (s) (let ((*package* (find-package "INFIX-VARS"))) (string->prefix s)))
(defun substitute-var (expr v val)
   (let ((v (etypecase v (symbol v) (string (intern v (find-package "INFIX-VARS"))))))
    (subst expr v val)))
(defun eval-expr (e)
  (etypecase e
    (number e)
    (list
      (ecase (car e)
        (+ (apply #'+ (mapcar #'eval-expr (cdr e))))))))
```

Comment: *symbols from other packages can be written*: you can bind the colon character to an error function in your readtable (with non-terminating-p set to NIL)

Comment: @coredump Ah clever. One would probably want to do the same for `!` (escape to Lisp)